# How to use a python script to change db connection variables in Pentaho?

Tags: python, pentaho, pentaho-spoon, pentaho-data-integration, pdi

I'm trying to minimize the work when copying a transformation from one environment to another. Currently, we have to manually change every db connection variables when switching from dev environment to uat environment. Im trying to write a python script which will change the values of those variables depending on the environment.

Right now I have a python variable which can hold values for environment names like 'dev' or 'uat' or 'prod'. Depending on the value of this variable python can change the values of db variables. The user only has to change the environment variable on python script. Is there a way to optimize this. Or lets say at some point we have the connection details are changed, in that case we have to change scripts for every transformations. Is there a way to have a base python script that contains the connection values and another script on Pentaho which contains the environment variable that user can change.

Comment: If you are using the community edition of PDI and aren't much invested in Pentaho technology it might be worth using apache-hop instead of PDI. The community edition of PDI isn't being developed much, and old PDI developers parted from 8.2 version of PDI and started updating old technology and adding concepts like projects and environments as base for hop. There's a tool to migrate your pentaho transformations/workflows to hop pipelines/workflows, so much of your old work can be automatically translated to the new tool (not all the steps, but a great amount of them).

Comment: You can also try if the plugin created to add the concept of environments to PDI still works in your version: https://github.com/mattcasters/kettle-environment, look for blog posts on how to use it. Or, instead of installing a new plugin, you can work with the kettle.properties file. You can add variables there for your installation, and use different kettle.properties files to switch environments.

Comment: Another option we do is to just load all database configurations (host, port, user, etc) from a encrypted file or database, which is located on a fixed relative location on the environment itself. Whenever we push the code, it will just fetch the database connection from the local environment file / database and therefore no issue with diffrent environments.